# Pandas query function with like and date

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a python function that get a pandas dataframe and perform on it a condiotion by the function "query" of DataFrame.

So simple conditions like =, != and all that it's ok.

But I want it to perform a conditions with "like". Is that possible?

Also, I want to check if some column is bigger than "now"...

How could I do that ?

Comment: It depends how you want to use `like`. The answer will change accordingly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Demo:

```
In [166]: now = pd.datetime.today()

In [167]: df
Out[167]:
        date              s
0 2017-01-18  sample string
1 2017-12-01      blah-blah
2 2017-08-17          a key

In [168]: df.query("s.str.contains('key')", engine='python')
Out[168]:
        date      s
2 2017-08-17  a key

In [169]: df.query("s.str.contains('key') or date > @now", engine='python')
Out[169]:
        date          s
1 2017-12-01  blah-blah
2 2017-08-17      a key
```

Comment: Great ! Thank you !

Answer (score 8):

I think `LIKE` functionality is not implemented to `query` native way, need [`contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html), [`match`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.match.html) and [similar functions](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/text.html#method-summary).

For compare with today:

```
now = pd.datetime.today()

df.query("col > @now")
```